# Add click event on bootstrap tab?

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, javascript, jquery, bootstrap

How to add an onClick event on Joomla bootstrap tabs.

https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHtmlBootstrap.html

```
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.startTabSet', 'myTab', array('active' => 'monday'));
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'myTab', 'monday',  JText::_('MONDAY', true));
// all html code
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab');
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTabSet');
```

I have tried

```
jQuery('#monday').click(function(e) {
    alert('hello');
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried anything of your own or done any research on the matter so far?

Comment: Take a look at [tabs events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events) on bootstrap docs.

Comment: @Lodder This is the only thing I tried `jQuery('#monday').click(function(e){alert('hello'); });` and it doesnt work.

Comment: @ReneKorss I referred Bootstrap 2.3.2 event and added `jQuery('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) { alert('working'); });` inside `ready` and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @Malaiselvan - I know it's been years now but would you mind ading your solution as a proper answer below and marking it as accepted? Thank you

Comment: @Malaiselvan please resolve this page so that the system stops bumping it to the top of the active questions list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. I'm making an AJAX call, but you can do whatever you want. I added the following to my javascript code in the document ready function. It is stolen and edited from the actual bootstrap framework code, but doesn't override it. I guess you can add multiple functions to the onclick event.

```
        $(document).on('click.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-toggle="pill"]', function (e) {
        /* These two calls are made in the bootstrap framework code and do not seem to be necessary here. I think this call is adding, not overriding the bootstrap code.*/
        //e.preventDefault();
        //$(this).tab('show');
        var tab_link = e.target.toString();
        var start = tab_link.indexOf('#')+1;
        var tabval = tab_link.substring(start);

        // Make AJAX call to set active_tab.
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php?option=com_myjoomlacomponent&format=raw&view=diagnosis&layout=edit&action=setactivetab&tabval='+tabval,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data, status, jq) {
                console.log(status);
            },
            error: function (jq, status, e) {
                console.log('Made AJAX call in document.ready function, error is: '+e+', status is: '+status);
            }
        });
    })
```